# ssl handshake failure with COPY on PostgreSQL

Tags: ssl, postgresql, copy, psql

I'm restoring a `CSV` file to database with `COPY` command. The csv file is bziped. I use this command:

```
bunzip2 -c -d online-20110923000001.csv.bz2 | psql -U user -h 127.0.0.1 -d testdb -c "COPY data FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER;"
```

After some time it stops with:

```
SSL error: ssl handshake failure
connection was lost to database
```

Log file shows:

```
2012-03-06 10:01:10 IRST STATEMENT:  COPY data FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER;
2012-03-06 10:01:10 IRST LOG:  SSL error: ssl handshake failure
2012-03-06 10:01:10 IRST CONTEXT:  COPY data, line 8349702
2012-03-06 10:01:10 IRST STATEMENT:  COPY data FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER;
2012-03-06 10:01:10 IRST LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2012-03-06 10:01:10 IRST CONTEXT:  COPY data, line 8349702
```

Could anyone help? Does `psql` use SSL? How can I disable it? I restarted the command above and now it is working fine again.
I haven't changed any PostgreSQL configuration. I'm running PostgreSQL 8.4.10 on Debian 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the docs suggest that you can disable ssl connections using the option sslmode like so;

```
$ psql "service=myservice sslmode=disable"
```

this also seems to be the standard way including passing args explicitly, of which there are a few examples on google;

```
$ bunzip2 -c -d online-20110923000001.csv.bz2 |  \
psql "host=127.0.0.1 user=joe password=foo dbname=testdb sslmode=disable" \
-c "COPY data FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER;"
```

THere is also the conf file option so you could put these commands in /etc/postgresql-8.4/pg_service.conf

```
[myservice]
dbname=testdb
user=user
host=127.0.0.1
password=password.here
```

and that might work like so;

```
bunzip2 -c -d online-20110923000001.csv.bz2 | psql "service=myservice sslmode=disable"  -c "COPY data FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER;"
```

but its rejecting that invocation for me, but it is along those lines, and I dont have an postgresql server at hand, but I can update the answer later when I get on a work box.

the example page from the manual is;
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html

(hmm. I should have really left this question to someone who uses postgresql day-to-day... ;-)